# Displaying all prefixes of a word in C++

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to do is display all the suffixes of a word as such:

word:  `house`

print:

```
h
ho
hou
hous
house
```

What I did is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char cuvant[100];
   int i,k;

   cin>>cuvant;

   for(i=0;i<strlen(cuvant);i++)
   {
       for(k=0;k<i;k++)
       {
           if(k==0)
           {
               cout<<cuvant[k]<<endl;
           }else
           {
             for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
                 if(k==i) cout<<endl;
                 cout<<cuvant[k];
             }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you explain in what way your program does not work. ie. What output _do_ you get?

Comment: Some paper, pencil, and a [discussion with your dubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) will probably be illuminating. And/or running in a actual *debugger*. The most perplexing item that needs self-examination is that for-k loop nested in.. a for-k loop.

Comment: Are you saying it should stop output at `"hous"`?

Comment: Is this homework or another kind of assignment for which you have to use only loops instead of using functions out of the std library for that task? Because it would be way easier with `std::string` and its `substr` member function.

Comment: It s not Hw, it’s for training in c++ @t.niese

Comment: @VladutMaican well even then one could argue, that learning c++  is to use the functionality the std provides instead of reinventing the wheel. Anyhow, if it is about learning I would suggest that you use the debugger of your IDE to step trough your code to see where the values change in a way that you did not expect because that's an essential part of the learning process.

Comment: Printing all prefixes is a task for a single loop right? (loop over the prefixes; for each prefix - print it). Why do you have nested loops? 

Also, you're mixing C and C++, which is generally not a good practice / idea. From the looks of it, you're a programming beginner. My (subjective) advice is that you focus on a single language, say the easier C, and learn to program in it - then learn C++, not in a mixture.

Comment: @YuriFeldman C and C++ have some fundamental differences, and if you want to learn C++ then learn C++ and don't start with C.

Comment: @YuriFeldman [Stop Teaching C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk)

Comment: @t.niese +1 But I can hardly imagine starting programming from C++.. - I think I don't know anybody who did so

Comment: @user1810087 Thanks, will now actually watch it :-)

Comment: Be clear, what do you ant to achieve? What's wrong?

Comment: @YuriFeldman that depends on how c++ is taught. Loops, strings, vectors, ... can be used without knowing oop, and in-depth details of templates. But I agree that many tutorials/courses are bad in teaching C++. But the same is often true for C (and other languages). So if you learn bad habits with C, and then you try to apply those while learning C++ making it even worse. Every language is hard to learn correctly, but there are some languages that let you to easier get away with bad habits (but that does not mean that you learn programming with those better).

Answer (score 2):

You're over-complicating it. Here's a simpler way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main() {
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  for (std::string::size_type i = 0, size = s.size(); i != size; ++i)
    std::cout << std::string_view{s.c_str(), i + 1} << '\n';
}
```

---

If you don't have access to a C++17 compiler, you can use this one:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  for (auto const& ch : s) {
    std::copy(s.c_str(), (&ch + 1),
              std::ostream_iterator<decltype(ch)>(std::cout));
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I like the `std::string_view` best.

Answer (score 2):

Even so, I think it would be better for your learning progress to use a debugger to finger out the problem yourself. Here the problems with your code:

For the `i=0` (the first iteration of your outer loop)  the `for(k=0;k<i;k++)` will not be executed at all, as `k<0` evaluates to `false`.

And having a running variable (`k`) that you change in two `for` loops that are nested, is most of the time also an indication that something is wrong.

So what you want to do: You want to create each possible prefix, so you want to create `n` strings with the length of `1` to `n`. So your first idea with the outer loop is correct. But you overcomplicate the inner part.

For the inner part, you want to print all chars from the index `0` up to `i`.

```
int main() {
    char cuvant[100];

    std::cin >> cuvant;

    // loop over the length of the string
    for (int i = 0, size = strlen(cuvant); i < size; i++) {

        // print all chars from 0 upto to i (k<=0)
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            std::cout << cuvant[k];
        }
        // print a new line after that
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But instead of reinventing the wheel I would use the functions the std provides:

```
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = s.size(); i < size; i++) {
        std::cout << s.substr(0, i + 1) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this very simple string suffix task you can just use:

```
void main()
{
    std::string s = "house";
    std::string s2;
    for(char c : s) 
    {
        s2 += c;
        cout << s2 << endl;
    }
}
```

For more complicated problems you may be interested to read about [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)

Answer (score -2):

#### Your code is wrong, the following code can fulfill your requirements

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char cuvant[100];
   int i,k;

   cin>>cuvant;
   for(i=0;i<strlen(cuvant);i++)
   {
        for (k = 0; k <= i; ++k)
        {
            cout<<cuvant[k];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: calculating `strlen` *every* iteration is just an awful idea...